# HTML5 audio tag won't show on iOS browsers after adding src with jquery

Tags: jquery, ios, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I'm at a loss. I have a one-page site that attempts to display about 14 mp3s. Because of the file sizes, the control sources are not appended/loaded until user clicks a link to display that panel. I do this by the following jquery (depending on which link is chosen):

```
$("#post-2 audio source").attr("src", "/Content/audio/<file>.mp3").detach().appendTo($("#audio2"));
$("#post-2 embed source").attr("src", "/Content/audio/<file>.mp3").detach().appendTo($("#audio2"));
```

This works on desktop but iOS Safari will not show the controls. Someone reported that it's not working in FF, but I see it working there okay.

Basically, the script to load the source into the DOM just plain won't work. Any ideas? Client does not want to use SoundCloud, even though that's the interim solution and works perfectly.

Any thoughts/recommendations/input would be greatly appreciated here.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact that the audio controls are embedded in the easytabs plugin?

Comment: Yes, when I commented out easytabs, then the audio controls display properly on Safari mobile. If anyone knows a fix or a workaround, that would be great.